# Google Analytics API - Filtering via .NET - So Close!

Tags: .net, google-analytics-api

Good afternoon!  I've been searching StackOverflow and the web for about 24 hours now, and I haven't found an answer yet.  I hope I'm missing something simple that a more experienced API user can point out for me.

I'm querying the Google Analytics API using their .NET library.  This request works:

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?start-index=1&max-results=500&dimensions=ga:date&end-date=2011-01-06&ids=ga:________&metrics=ga:visitors,ga:visits&start-date=2011-01-06
```

...but I'd like to filter the results.  I've tried a single very simple filter which does not require URL encoding:

```
filters=ga:city!@Minsk
```

All I get is the maddeningly vague "400 bad request" error.  I get the same result using the equals operator:

```
DataQuery  query = new DataQuery(URL);
...
query.Filters = "ga:city==Minsk"
```

Ditto if I encode the equals signs as %3D.  This gets translated into "ga:city%253D%253DMinsk", according to the error message.  I've tried single-quoting "Minsk", and double-quoting it; no luck.

I'm stumped.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.  It turns out that filters have to be "compatible" with the dimensions and metrics actually expressed in a query.  Dropping ga:visitors allowed me to apply most of the filters I needed, though the combination of ga:pagePath and ga:campaign is not allowed with ga:visits... for some reason.  Here's the detail, but be warned: you may end up cross-eyed.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceValidCombos.html

Oh, and using the .NET library you do not need to encode equals signs or spaces in your filters.  I structured my filters like this:

```
private static readonly string  Filter = string.Join
  (
  ";", new string[]
    {
    "ga:city!=Simi Valley",  // URL encoding is handled for you
    "ga:pagePath!@/splash",
    "ga:pagePath!@static_test",
    "ga:networkLocation!@spring",
    "ga:networkLocation!@equinix asia pacific pte ltd"
    // ...
    }
  );
```

Hope this helps someone!