# Google Data API SDK - Filter encoding/escaping

Tags: javascript, api, soap

What do I have to do with DataQuery parameters to invoke Google Analytics API to get the same results as per http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html?
I tried URL encoding and escaping to no avail, and it should not be required as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618446/google-analytics-api-filtering-via-net-so-close).
I have a web service that calls Google Analytics via Google Data SDK API and I invoke it with SOAP library like this:

```
var Parameters = new SOAPClientParameters();
            Parameters.add('Ids', 'ga:MyID');   // This is the ID for internet-alumni.com, not proof.ptly.com
            Parameters.add('Filters', 'ga:pagePath=@/vic/mgs/ocd.aspx#h_');
            Parameters.add('Dimensions', 'ga:date,ga:pagePath');
            Parameters.add('Metrics', 'ga:visitors');
            Parameters.add('MaxEntries', 50);
            Parameters.add('DateFrom', '2011-07-01');
            Parameters.add('DateTo', '2011-06-01');

            SOAPClient.invoke(URL, Function, Parameters, true, OnDataReceived);
```

When debugging the service, parameters arrive exactly the same, although when calling DataQuery.Query it reports that start-date is not specified. When I encode # as %23 in Filters it queries without exception but returns no data, even though identical string in Data Feed Query Explorer returns correct data.

Comment: Hey. +1 For the gdataExplorer! Just wow! That link that is worth more than +1 point to me, just what a cool tool, pure awesomeness. 

Thanks for contributing. As for your question, I am quite clueless in the art of debugging cloud based web services so your on your own for a little while until a fellow so'er hopefully can clue you in.

 Good-luck!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to go around it simply by removing # and adding OR statement for ga:pagePath.